# Access 2013 control align short-cut menu wrong

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Does anyone else have completely the wrong short-cut menu options in Access 2013 form design, when aligning controls?

[image]

If so, any idea how to make them read To left, to right, to bottom and to top, or whatever it is they should say?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have the same thing. I only noticed it recently, pretty sure it was ok at first. This is the most obvious one but there are other menu options mixed up too, e.g. the Show Table option in query design is labelled Toolbox. Using 32b office on 64b win 7. I don't know what caused it, can anyone shed any light?

Update - did some more searching and found the culprit, it is update KB2752093 released earlier this month. Removing the update sorts the problem. Microsoft, why have you not corrected this yet?

Comment: Thanks.  I was using Office 32 on Windows 7 32.  Hadn't consciously installed an update.  It makes for an interesting training course, when the menu options appear wrong!  Strangely, although the captions are wrong they still do the right thing.